# Loading Wikipedia Dump into Elasticsearch

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, wikipedia

I want to load a XML Wikipedia dump like:
http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/wikimedia.org/dumps/enwiki/20171001/enwiki-20171001-pages-articles.xml.bz2
into Elasticsearch (5.6.4).
However, all tools and tutorials I found are outdated and not compatible with my Elasticsearch version.
Can anyone explain what's the best way to import the dump into Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two years ago wikimedia has made available dumps of the production elasticsearch indices.

The indices are exported every week and for each wiki there are two exports.

```
The content index, which contains only article pages, called content;
The general index, containing all pages. This includes talk pages, templates, etc, called general;
```

you can find them here http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/cirrussearch/current/

- create a mapping according your needs. For example:

  ```
  {
       "mappings": {
       "page": {
          "properties": {
             "auxiliary_text": {
                "type": "text"
             },
             "category": {
                "type": "text"
             },
             "coordinates": {
                "properties": {
                   "coord": {
                      "properties": {
                         "lat": {
                            "type": "double"
                         },
                         "lon": {
                            "type": "double"
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "country": {
                      "type": "text"
                   },
                   "dim": {
                      "type": "long"
                   },
                   "globe": {
                      "type": "text"
                   },
                   "name": {
                      "type": "text"
                   },
                   "primary": {
                      "type": "boolean"
                   },
                   "region": {
                      "type": "text"
                   },
                   "type": {
                      "type": "text"
                   }
                }
             },
             "defaultsort": {
                "type": "boolean"
             },
             "external_link": {
                "type": "text"
             },
             "heading": {
                "type": "text"
             },
             "incoming_links": {
                "type": "long"
             },
             "language": {
                "type": "text"
             },
             "namespace": {
                "type": "long"
             },
             "namespace_text": {
                "type": "text"
             },
             "opening_text": {
                "type": "text"
             },
             "outgoing_link": {
                "type": "text"
             },
             "popularity_score": {
                "type": "double"
             },
             "redirect": {
                "properties": {
                   "namespace": {
                      "type": "long"
                   },
                   "title": {
                      "type": "text"
                   }
                }
             },
             "score": {
                "type": "double"
             },
             "source_text": {
                "type": "text"
             },
             "template": {
                "type": "text"
             },
             "text": {
                "type": "text"
             },
             "text_bytes": {
                "type": "long"
             },
             "timestamp": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
             },
             "title": {
                "type": "text"
             },
             "version": {
                "type": "long"
             },
             "version_type": {
                "type": "text"
             },
             "wiki": {
                "type": "text"
             },
             "wikibase_item": {
                "type": "text"
             }
          }
       }
    }
  ```

  }

once you have created the index you just type:

```
zcat enwiki-current-cirrussearch-general.json.gz | parallel --pipe -L 2 -N 2000 -j3 'curl -s http://localhost:9200/enwiki/_bulk --data-binary @- > /dev/null'
```

Enjoy!

Comment: In addition to Lupanoide answer, you can download wiki-cirrussearch [Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=cirrus-mapping-dump&format=json&formatversion=2) & [Setting](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=cirrus-settings-dump&format=json&formatversion=2) configurations for Elasticsearch index

Comment: @AlonEirew No you can't! the mapping and setting are available only for ES 2.x . Schroder22 uses ES 5.6.4

Comment: I didn't know that, I'm using my own edited version on top of those (for elastic 6.2), they were a really good starting point for me :)

Comment: @Lupanoide I am using the latest 6.3 release and having a whole lot of trouble just creating the index. (I just want a barebones test setup to run queries against wikiquotes) Could you please add a default settings json file to the answer. Various articles mention installing plugin org.wikimedia.search:extra  Is it required? What version of elastic search do you recommend using when importing the index dump? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that you can indicize wikiquotes without a mapping? ES will create a new one for you. Then, Once you will have an automatical mapping you could change the datatype according your purposes, reindexing wikiquotes

Comment: @Lupanoide thanks! The blog post on the elastic website to load wiki in elastic is the source of the confusion. I do have two questions (1) about your zcat + parallel command. Why -L 2 and not -L 1? (2) do we need to install wikipedia search extra or analysis-icu plugins? I can't figure out what these are for...thx again for the reply.

Comment: I ve just tried with elastic 6.2.3 with enwiki-20181126-cirrussearch-content.json.gz . not success. it runs but It doesnt seem to flush the index. 0 documents after running the command.

Comment: @ArianPasquali Try to insert the headers in the curl call curl   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' Let us know

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways to import the wikipedia. I found two ways incuding using Logstash and write python coder directly.

- For using Logstash, you can refer to [Struggling in importing wikipedia into Elasticsearch](http://www.fuzihao.org/blog/2018/01/01/Struggling-in-importing-wikipedia-into-Elasticsearch/)
- For writing python code directly, please refer to [Struggling in importing wikipedia into Elasticsearch (2)](http://www.fuzihao.org/blog/2019/03/27/Struggling-in-importing-wikipedia-into-Elasticsearch-2/)